# How to figure out what is causing high CPU usage spikes for laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, performance, cpu-usage

I have built a relatively complicated system (CMS) which consists of two projects - admin site and user site. On admin site we create content and add it to pages. User site reflects those pages. The problem I'm facing is that something is causing 100% cpu usage spikes and I have no idea what that is. I've implemented data caching on crucial parts of the system which in my opinion are most resource-hungry but that only helped a little bit, It's still hitting that 100% cpu usage and the whole site goes down as it is unable to handle requests. We have around 300 users daily, which isn't that many IMO that Laravel app couldn't handle. I'm using blade templates so it's server-side rendering (thinking that a rework to a full Vue frontend might solve it but not sure). Perhaps someone could guide me to a right direction of what steps to take to figure out which function(s) in my code are causing these problems. I've tried using Laravel debugbar but I don't know what parameters are considered "satisfy-able". I've tried enabling long query logging in mysql, that provided no results. We're hosting on a dedicated server

CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6150 CPU @ 2.70GHz (4 core(s)).

OS AlmaLinux 8.4.

8GB RAM

I have a full control over the server but I'm not a qualified system administrator so I'm not sure if there's anything I can do to figure this out by running some terminal commands. I've tried running the "top" command and it just shows mysql and php-fpm as the processes that are consuming all of the CPU resources but that doesn't help me.

I'm suspecting there might be a memory leak somewhere but how may I find it?

[image]

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've run `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` and that displayed 1, which means it's a hard disc I suppose? And here is all the info you asked https://pastebin.com/GbdJLrGp

Comment: Thank you so much for actually getting deep into this issue of mine. My time zone is GMT+2. May I ask what Analysis are you performing? Is it automated analysis or do you look through my provided data manually?

Comment: The cpu usage appears to be extreme between 9-10 AM or 14-15:00 PM.  Any chance you could get SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; posted from each of these hours?  Your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; indicates the systems has been UP for 104 consecutive days (UPTIME).  Help us understand what you mean by 'whole site goes down', please.  We use your provided data with our specialized software to analyze your workload.

Comment: Here's the output of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; when CPU usage was 100% https://pastebin.com/f7WDgsvU . By "whole site goes down" I mean the server is clearly "choking" it's unable to even handle plesk interface properly, it's unresponsive and users start getting timeouts for our pages.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section
(use of SET GLOBAL variable_name=value; may SET these dynamic variables
and not require stop/start of instance)

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=64*1024  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 284,967
max_write_lock_count=16  # from ~ 4 billion to allow ReadData after nn locks
innodb_io_capacity=400  # from 200 to use more of available IOPS for your HDD
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1*1024*1024*1024  # from 128M to reduce innodb_data_reads RPS of 3
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 150000 for 1 second vs 15 second delay when busy
```

If any questions, please make contact.  CPU stress should be significantly reduced.  Many more opportunities exist to improve performance.

Observations,  A) handler_rollback averages 1 every 220 seconds - expensive operation for instance.  B) innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads in status report shows 251 RPS and is likely caused by frequent use of a table with no PRIMARY KEY.  C) select_scan averages 5 RPS - indicates index(s) missing that would improve performance of queries.  D) slow_query_log is ONLY useful when ON and when long_query_time is less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed explanation. Should I set those variable over sql queries? And if I do that it should just use these new settings without a need to restart mysql service?

Comment: By the way, I got a confirmation from our host that we do in fact use SSD my test was inaccurate because it's a virtual storage

Comment: Since you have SSD storage, innodb_io_capacity could go to 500 and be reasonable. Could we Skype TALk?  Thanks, Wilson Hauck GMT -6 hours.

Comment: This morning I've checked the server and saw there's a new error "the threshold of MYSQL memory usage has been exceeded" is this due to the changes I made? We can have a chat on Skype on Monday if that's okay? At around 10:00AM GMT-6?

Comment: Update: I am monitoring server load today and the suggested changes don't seem to be yielding any visible effects :/ we still get up to 100% cpu usage

Comment: @Matrix Sure, that wll be my 4 AM but I know you have a reason - that is your busy hour and our best hope of spotting troublesome activity.  Please SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=256*1024*1024; from your MySQL Command Prompt, now for the weekend.  What is your Skype ID? Thanks

Comment: @Matrix Planned connect in about 30 minutes still on your schedule this morning?  In Skype.com  search for  wlhauck@aol.com  to find me in Birmingham, AL  GMT -6 hours, please and connect when ready.  Thank you, Wilson Hauck

Comment: @Matrix         Was hoping we could connect this morning.  Life will go on. Please let me know if you would like to reschedule a Skype connect session.  Please request a couple date/time slots when you might be available.  Thank you, Wilson Hauck

Comment: I am so sorry, I must've miscalculated the time differences. I wrote you on skype just now